# Fill a shape with a random color in java

Tags: java, graphics, colors

In this program I am doing, I need to be able to fill shapes with random colors. I am confused on how to actually fill in the shape. I am able to generate a random color. I have looked around online and found some sources talk about implementing the `Paint` interface and use the method `setPaint()` on the shape you are wishing to draw and then invoke the `fill` method. I tried this but was unsuccessful. Maybe I just had it wrong. Here is what I had.

```
Random rand = new Random();
float r = rand.nextFloat();
float g = rand.nextFloat();
float b = rand.nextFloat();

Color randomColor = new Color (r, g, b);
```

This was in a constructor of a superclass where I actually have `randomColor` as an attribute of the class. So to access that element in the subclass, I provide a basic getter that just returns the Color.

In the subclass I have this:

```
Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), height);
rectangle.setPaint(getColor());
rectangle.fill();
g2.draw(rectangle);
```

The error I am getting is something about typecasting `rectangle` but any typecast I try it's not working. I'm not exactly sure how to fix this issue. Any ideas? Or is there an easier/better way to fill a shape with a random color? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `rand.nextInt(256);` make more sense?

Comment: Typecasting has nothing to do with random colors. Show us the exact error you get and the code that's in.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the methods you are calling on the rectangle on the Graphics2D

```
Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), height);
g2.setPaint(getColor());
g2.fill(rectangle);
g2.draw(rectangle);
```

Comment: Aweomse! It worked. Thank you so much. This much much easier than what I was trying to do. How did you know to use the `setPaint` and `fill` methods on `g2` and not `rectangle`?

Comment: Because I've done this before: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

Comment: I do have another question, something I just noticed with my program now. The way I had it before I filled the shape with a color, when you clicked on the shape, the shape was translates down and right by 1 pixel each and then redrawn multiple times to show that it was "selected". Here is what it looks like (this is actually my screen, so this is my program running currently): https://gyazo.com/0af4f9b88acdaf682f763a255df38202

The problem I am having now is that the whole shape is filled with a color so when its selected, then it is just redrawn with that same color so you can't really tell.

Comment: I am wondering how I can fill the shape with a random color and then outline the shape with black that way it's still filled, but when you select it, you get the little redrawn thing. I am new to graphics programming so I am still learning some things. Here is how it looks now: https://gyazo.com/b172d939963106d9ba4290e81320d77e

Comment: After your fill(rect) call, do setPaint(outlineColor) draw(rect)

Comment: @GenericUser01, `Aweomse! It worked. Thank you so much.` - don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to fill shapes with random colors

Then you should create a class (ColoredShape) that contains two properties:

1. Shape
2. Color

Then you can create an ArrayList to hold instances of this class.

```
ArrayList<ColoredShape> shapes = new ArrayList<ColoredShape>();
shapes.add( new ColoredShape(aShape, generateRandomColor());
shapes.add( new ColoredShape(anotherShape, generateRandomColor());
```

Then in the paintComponent() method of your panel you iterate through the ArrayList and paint all the shapes:

```
for (ColoredShape shape: shapes)
{
    g2.setColor(shape.getColor());
    g2.draw(shape.getShape());
}
```

For a working example of this approach check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Comment: I think this is a mistake: ArrayList<Shape, Color> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape, Color>();

Comment: @ControlAltDel, oops, fixed :)